# Em Php, enviar dado oculto para o banco de dados

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário em uma aplicação onde o usuário precisa cadastrar o Celular colocando o código do Brasil (+55), porém quero facilitar o formulário enviando o +55 de forma oculta para o BD, la no banco de dados precisa aparecer cadastrado assim (+5544999990000) porém o usuário só vai entrar com DDD e o numero, segue o formulário que preciso editar.

É melhor editar o código, ou deixar o +55 direto no banco de dados?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola tudo bem? Isso pode ser resolvido para quando voce realizar a query de envio de dados com php, voce deixa uma string fixa de "+55" e concatena com o valor do formulario, que é o numero do usuario.

```
INSERT INTO tb_usuarios (nome, numeroCEL) values ('alan', '+55'.$valueFromCampoNumero);
```

Desculpe se eu errei algo, to enferrujado em php e MySQL

Comment: Alan obrigado pela ajuda, mas eu consigo colocar o +55 direto no código acima?

Comment: Sim, voce pode utilizar a tag "value", assim quando o usuario se deparar com o campo, a string "+55" vai estar "digitada", assim ele poderá editar esse valor
Mas o que eu te recomendo é fazer a estrategia do banco de dados mesmo, bate mais com o que voce parece querer.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Alan..

Comment: De nada! Se isso realmente resolveu seu problema, por favor marque a minha resposta como correta, assim as pessoas não precisam entrar ja que esta solucionada